# could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 3 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: hadoop, nutch

This error keeps being thrown in my hadoop nutch crawler.  There is plenty of free space on all nodes.  I am unsure how to continue.

The complete error is:

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /crawl/segments/20170211181653/crawl_parse/part-00000 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
```

Edited to include output of hdfs dfsadmin -report

```
Configured Capacity: 85316812800 (79.46 GB)
Present Capacity: 84047159296 (78.28 GB)
DFS Remaining: 83300806656 (77.58 GB)
DFS Used: 746352640 (711.78 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.89%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 10.0.0.175:50010 (ip-10-0-0-175.ec2.internal)
Hostname: ip-10-0-0-175.ec2.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 28438937600 (26.49 GB)
DFS Used: 222629888 (212.32 MB)
Non DFS Used: 422780928 (403.20 MB)
DFS Remaining: 27793526784 (25.88 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.78%
DFS Remaining%: 97.73%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Feb 21 20:31:36 UTC 2017

Name: 10.0.0.4:50010 (ip-10-0-0-4.ec2.internal)
Hostname: ip-10-0-0-4.ec2.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 28438937600 (26.49 GB)
DFS Used: 248160256 (236.66 MB)
Non DFS Used: 423477248 (403.86 MB)
DFS Remaining: 27767300096 (25.86 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.87%
DFS Remaining%: 97.64%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Feb 21 20:31:38 UTC 2017

Name: 10.0.0.11:50010 (ip-10-0-0-11.ec2.internal)
Hostname: ip-10-0-0-11.ec2.internal
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 28438937600 (26.49 GB)
DFS Used: 275562496 (262.80 MB)
Non DFS Used: 423395328 (403.78 MB)
DFS Remaining: 27739979776 (25.83 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.97%
DFS Remaining%: 97.54%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue Feb 21 20:31:36 UTC 2017
```

Comment: Are the datanodes running? Can you update the post with the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report`

Comment: @franklinsijo just updated the post

Comment: @franklinsijo I'm relatively new to this.  How would I check that sort of thing?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes it can connect to them

Comment: what does this command return `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get`

Comment: @franklinsijo `Safe mode is OFF`

Comment: @franklinsijo my apologies.  How would I check that?

Comment: @franklinsijo i ran the df command and it says that the / directory has 86% usage.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @franklinsijo this was in the client node

Comment: @franklinsijo up until this point I haven't been able to ssh into the datanodes.  How would I check their free space?

Comment: I always get the permission denied publickey error

Comment: Check out the datanode log, it always give you more information why the data could not be able to replicated.

Answer (score -1):

1. Firstly stop the Hadoop Cluster.

> bin/stop-all.sh

2. Delete all the files from cache and temp directory .

> cache directory is present in the var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache folder.
>   temp directory you mentioned in the mapred-site.xml using property
>   hadoop.tmp.dir.

3. Format the namenode

> bin/hadoop namenode -format

4. Start the Cluster

> bin/start-all.sh

this will resolve your problem.

Comment: -1. This does not *solve* the problem. This is a workaround at best, useful *only* when the previous setup was incorrectly formatted and there is no data to be lost.

Comment: Quit posting these "just restart/reinstall it" solutions.